# Why I can't call the class in the C# composition

Tags: c#, class, oop, methods

HEllo I have an OOP Homewrok using class composition , I've Created Two Class 1.date and I can call it in the main 2.employee but I can't call it to create an object here is the code

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public class date
        {
            private int day;
            private int mounth;
            private int year;

            public date(int day, int mounth, int year)
            {
                this.day = day;
                this.mounth = mounth;
                this.year = year;

            }
            public void Display()
            {

                Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}", day, mounth, year);

            }

            public class employee
            {
                private string name;
                private date hire_date;
                private date Emplye_birth;
                private int number;

                public employee(int number, string name, date bd, date hd)
                {
                    this.name = name;
                    this.number = number;
                    hire_date = hd;
                    Emplye_birth = bd;

                }
                public void printEmplyy()
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Employee number {0} \n name:{1}", number, name);
                    Console.WriteLine("hire date of {0}", name);
                    hire_date.Display();
                    Console.WriteLine("birthday of {0}", name);
                    Emplye_birth.Display();

                }
            }

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            date Khaled_birth = new date(10, 10, 1995);
            date khaled_hire = new date(10, 10, 2017);
            string user;
            int number;
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the user and password ");
            Console.Write("USERNAME:"); user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Password"); number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            /*
            employee khaled_info = new employee(number, user, khaled_hire, Khaled_birth); 
           that code wont to run 
             */
            if (user == "khaled" && number == 001995)
            {
                /*    khaled_info.printEmplyy(); 
               that code wont to run
                 */
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read and *report* what "wont to run" means. Also take time to *search* for said error message(s)/symptom(s).

Comment: Did you mean for `employee` to be a *nested class* within `Date`?  I don't think an "employee" is an attribute of a "date" in any conceptual way.

Comment: The employee class is nested in the date class. Extract it. And extract both Date and Employee out of Program. You must new up an instance of the employee. You will get fewer namespace and scope oddities if you don't nest classes.

Comment: Why do you need a `Date` class? Why not use the built in `Date` class?

Comment: Ugh, nesting classes are almost never a good idea, certainly not while just learning the language. Hopefully that was just a typo...

Comment: For sure a missing parenthesis. Nesting employee inside date makes no sense.

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'employee' could not be found

Comment: Is there a need to write your own Date class instead using `DateTime`?

Comment: @user3608930 Clearly not because you can't compile it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `employee` class is nested inside of your `date` class. If you pull it out, then you can access it. Like so:

```
public class date
{
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;

    public date(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}", day, month, year);
    }
}

public class employee
{
    private string name;
    private date hire_date;
    private date Employee_birth;
    private int number;

    public employee(int number, string name, date bd, date hd)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        hire_date = hd;
        Employee_birth = bd;
    }

    public void printEmployee()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Employee number {0} \n name:{1}", number, name);
        Console.WriteLine("hire date of {0}", name);
        hire_date.Display();
        Console.WriteLine("birthday of {0}", name);
        Employee_birth.Display();
    }
}
```

Comment: WOOW man thank you I Forgot to put the {} to close the date class offf sorry guys my fault :/

Answer (score 0):

Or use full path to employee class like:

```
Program.date.employee khaled_info = new Program.date.employee(...);
```

BTW you have 1 string formatting error.